# Where did Rash"i's commentary leave off when he died?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, rashi

Where did Rash"i's commentary leave off when died? Did he finish it? What was he working on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On [Bava Basra 29a](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3317&size=1).

He also died on [Makkos 19b](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3872&size=1). See six lines down in the narrow lines.

Not sure where he died first.

Comment: correct answer.

Comment: "Not sure where he died first" - um...